# Xamarin Forms WebView Check When Website Address Changed

Tags: webview, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have the following code that sets up a WebView inside my Xamarin.Forms Cross Platform application:

```cs
ReportsListWebView = new WebView()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent
};            

URLReportsListWebView = new  UrlWebViewSource
{
    Url = "http://192.168.0.96/MyWebsite/App/MiniMyWebsite?ActionType=Listing&Params=Reports"
};

ReportsListWebView.Source = URLReportsListWebView;

grid.Children.Add(ReportsListWebView, 0, 4, 0, 1);
```

The situation is that there is listing within the website that I am referencing in the WebView. When the user selects an item in the listing on the webpage it has javascript that changes the url of the website (appends #SelectedItem=1 to the url). I just want to be able to recognize this change from within the application.

I've checked the URLReportsListWebView.Url but it doesn't seem to update with the latest changes. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a limitation on the xamarin forms webview control. The work around was to create a custom renderer which the Xamarin support provided me a great same showing how to accomplish this at [github.com/jgold6/XFormsWebViewCustomRenderer/tree/master](https://github.com/jgold6/XFormsWebViewCustomRenderer/tree/master)

Comment: i need WindowsPhone implementation. Have you done it?

Comment: Hi AEM, Yeah accomplished it. Should have code in the github repo.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done a few tests against *http://www.yahoo.com* it appears to be updating the **WebView.Source** property ok, even with *query string* attribues.

Are you just updating the *location* of the *current webpage* rather than *navigating* to a new page?

Maybe this could be the reason why its not working for you?

If so, after the change, you will then be able to monitor the **.Source** property for the newly navigated webpage as there is no event handler or anything to hook into to get notified when a page has been navigated to / fully loaded.

**Update 1:-**

Try the following that is working for me.

It should produce updates similar to the following:-

*http://www.yahoo.com*

*https://fr.yahoo.com/?p=us*

*https://fr.news.yahoo.com/syrie-jihadistes-exécutent-160-soldats-43-casques-bleus-050134941.html*

*http://www.tv3g.bouquettv.mobi/wap/landing/landing2.asp?c=LFYAH_TVGREEN_AAAMMM&IDLanding=16972&tag=0&Alea=7.906741E-02&Al=MM201408290946299694*

Code:-

```
        StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
        };
        //
        WebView objWebView1 = new WebView();            
        objWebView1.HeightRequest = 300;
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objWebView1);
        //
        UrlWebViewSource objUrlToNavigateTo = new UrlWebViewSource()
        {
            Url = "http://www.yahoo.com"
        };
        objWebView1.Source = objUrlToNavigateTo;
        //
        //
        Button cmdButton1 = new Button();
        cmdButton1.Text = "Show Me Current Url";
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(cmdButton1);
        //
        cmdButton1.Clicked += ((o2, e2) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((objWebView1.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url);
            });
        //
        //
        this.Content = objStackLayout;
```

Comment: Hi Pete, Thanks for the response. Im getting a different outcome to you than. Dont know whether we might doing something different. I'm changing the href/url within the website itself. i.e. In javascript on select of a row in the listing I change the websites href to another location using location.href = "http://www.test.com";. After this occurs i hit a breakpoint in the app itself and check the source of the webview and its still showing the address that it first went to. Any ideas?

Comment: This is what I was referring to when changing the location, i.e. in Javascript.  Have you tried navigating to a different page perhaps?, or perhaps even to the same page without doing this via Javascript?  It maybe that the location.href is not triggering things off within the Xamarin.Forms WebView control the way they do when you do a form post etc.  I haven't specifically tried the location.href change of url with my test but this maybe why it doesn't work perhaps in your case.

Comment: Hi Pete, Yeah I tried just navigating between pages (not using href javascript) and it still doesnt pick up any changes in my code. I know its a big ask, but would you be able to shoot me an example of your code that is recognizing the change? Thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Please see **Update 1** on the main post.  Just as another check can you ensure you are using the latest **Xamarin.Forms** *(stable)* also?

Comment: Hi Pete, Sorry for the late reply. I've tried your exact code snippet and still am not seeing the change. I've double checked my dll's are the latest. This is doing my head in. Just wondering what else could be different. All my controls and code is written in a Portable class at runtime using Xamarin.Forms and is shared across both an android and ios deployment. Any chance you could just give me a rar/zip of your code/sln and i'll check the differences. Cheers

Comment: If you send an email to myself from my Profile page I will re-create the small example and send to you.  Also it may be worth while to send more what your doing perhaps and I will be able to help more hopefully.    Once solved, we can update on here to let others know the outcome if anything new of interest.

Comment: Cool Pete. Just shot u an email.

Comment: Hi Pete, I was never able to get any wins with this until asking xamarin. They ended up saying that I need to use Custom Renderers to achieve this. They made an example of this: https://github.com/jgold6/XFormsWebViewCustomRenderer/tree/master

Comment: Hi, I did send you the solution on email but didn't hear back, however I tested this only on *WindowsPhone* and I didn't realize at the time that you was testing on *Android* (finally i saw the tag for *monodroid*).  I re-tested on *Android* and yes - this is a bug and doesn't work on *Android* devices.  I just would had expected something so simple to work on all three platforms without the need of a custom renderer but at the moment it looks like the only way until they integrate the changes into a future release.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't yet have a custom renderer, you'll need to refer to Xamarin documentation to learn how to custom render Xamarin.Forms WebView.

If you already have the custom renderer, inside the CustomRenderer object, you should access the NativeWebview object and assign HandleShouldStartLoad to its ShouldStartLoad event handler. My mistake was that I assigned HandleShouldStartLoad to the event handler of the renderer itself, which won't work.