# Detect URL change with Xamarin.Forms Webview and Compare current URL to original URL

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview

So I'm creating an app that uses Xamarin.Forms Webview. I'm trying to detect when the URL changes and if it does then compare the Original URL with the Current URL and then show or hide a button depending. The buttons purpose is to go back to the previous page and keep going until it reaches it's original destination. I only want this "go back" button to show when the user is not on the homescreen. Otherwise, always show.

I've tried everything with if(webview.cangoback...) but that doesn't detect the url change. I've tried setting a string that is equal to the original URL and using .Equals to compare the webview.source (which is where I'm currently at)

I just started looking into webviewNavigating but still nothing.

```
namespace Webview_Test
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static string CurrentUrl { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            string CurrentUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

            var _webView = new WebView()
            {
                Source = "https://www.google.com/",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            Button BackButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Go Back",
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("990000"),
                TextColor = Color.White
            };
            BackButton.Clicked += OnBackButtonClicked;

            void OnBackButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                _webView.GoBack();
            }


            Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(36, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
                },
                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }
                }
            };

            grid.Children.Add(_webView, 0, 6, 0, 7);

            if (_webView.Source.Equals(CurrentUrl))
            {
                grid.Children.Remove(BackButton);
            }
            else
            {
                grid.Children.Add(BackButton, 2, 4, 4, 6);
            }

            Content = grid;
        }
    }
}
```

My expected result is that on the homepage the button that says "go back" doesn't show. But on any page other than the homepage it should show the "go back" button. In logical terms it's if OriginalURL = CurrentURL don't show button. if OriginalURL != CurrentURL show button.

Comment: the Navigating event should fire every time a new page begins to load - have you tried that?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Navigating event? i'll put some examples below.

```
public string OriginalURL = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
private async void Webview_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Url != OriginalURL)
   { 
      //Write code, show the button or use if(webview.CanGoBack){//your code}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be late, but this helps, easy, quick, without any problem.

```
var url = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("window.location.href");
```

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I create custom renderer of webView on each platform to get the current url of webView, it's a little complex but it works finally.

In **iOS** part, override the `LoadingFinished` method to get the current url:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App374.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer,IUIWebViewDelegate
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {   // perform initial setup
                UIWebView myWebView = (UIWebView)this.NativeView;

                Delegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate(e.NewElement as WebView);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.WebView formsWebView;

        public CustomWebViewDelegate(WebView webView)
        {
            formsWebView = webView;
        }

        public override void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
        {
            var url = webView.Request.Url.AbsoluteUrl.ToString();

            MainPage.CurrentUrl = webView.Request.Url.AbsoluteString;

            MainPage.checkToShowButton();
        }

    }
}
```

In Android part, override the `OnPageFinished` method to get the current url:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyWebView), typeof (MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App374.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                // lets get a reference to the native control
                var webView = (global::Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                webView.SetInitialScale(0);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

            MainPage.CurrentUrl = url;

            MainPage.checkToShowButton();
        }
    }
}
```

And code behiend, check whether to show the go back button after every navigation:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static string CurrentUrl { get; set; }

        public static MyWebView _webView;

        public static Grid grid;

        public static Button BackButton;


        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            string CurrentUrl = "https://www.baidu.com/";

            _webView = new MyWebView()
            {
                Source = CurrentUrl,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };


            BackButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Go Back",
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("990000"),
                TextColor = Color.White
            };

            grid = new Grid
            {
                 //...
            };

            grid.Children.Add(_webView, 0, 6, 0, 7);


            Content = grid;

            checkToShowButton();

            //Button click
            BackButton.Clicked += OnBackButtonClicked;
            void OnBackButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                _webView.GoBack();        

                checkToShowButton();

                if (_webView.CanGoBack == false)
                {
                    grid.Children.Remove(BackButton);
                }
            }
        }

        //Check whther to show goBack button
        public static void checkToShowButton()
        {

            if ("https://www.baidu.com/".Equals(MainPage.CurrentUrl) || CurrentUrl == null || CurrentUrl == "")
            {
                grid.Children.Remove(BackButton);
            }
            else
            {

                if (grid != null)
                {
                    grid.Children.Add(BackButton, 2, 4, 4, 6);
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public class MyWebView : WebView { }
```

I uploaded my whole sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/WebView-Current-Url-Xamarin.forms) and you can check it. Let me know if it works.

***Note***: I tested the `_webView.Navigated` and I found it only fires at the first time when loading the webView.

```
 _webView.Navigated += (sender, e) => {

 };
```

Refer : [webview-check-when-website-address-changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517298/xamarin-forms-webview-check-when-website-address-changed)